# Google Maps-style quad-tree of materials on a single plane in Three.js – 1x1, 2x2, 4x4 and 8x8

Tags: three.js

I'm trying and failing to work out how to achieve a quad-tree of materials (images) on a single plane, much like a Google Maps-style zoomable tile that gets more accurate the closer you get.

In short, I want to be able to have a 1x1 image texture (covering a plane that is 256 units wide and tall) that can then be replaced with a 2x2 texture, that can then be replaced with a 4x4 texture, and so on.

Like the image example below…

[image: Texture levels]

Ideally, I want to avoid having to create a different plane for each zoom level / number of segments. A perfect solution would allow me to break a single plane into 8x8 segments (highest zoom) and update the number of textures on the fly. So it would start with a 1x1 texture across all 64 (8x8) segments, then change into a 2x2 texture with each texture covering 4x4 segments, and so on.

Unfortunately, I can't work out how to do this. I explored setting the `materialIndex` for each face but you aren't able to update those after the first render so that wouldn't work. I've tried looking into UV coordinates but I don't understand how it would work in this situation, nor how to actually implement that in Three.js – there is little in the way of documentation / examples for this specific case.

A vertex shader is another option that came up in research, but again I don't know enough to understand how to construct that.

I'd appreciate any and all help with this, it will be a technique that proves valuable for other Three.js users I'm sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to do, whether you are talking about texture atlasing (looking up and different textures based on current setting/zooms) but if you are looking for quad-tree based texturing that increases in detail as you zoom in then this is essentially what mipmaping is and does.

(It can be also be used to do all sorts of weird things because of that, but that's another adventure entirely)

Generally mipmapping is automatic based on the filtering you use - however it sounds like you need more control over it.

I created an example hidden away in the three.js source tree which may help:

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_materials_texture_manualmipmap.html

Which shows you how to load each mipmap level in manually, rather than have it just be automatically generated.

HTH

Comment: Thanks Ben! I don't yet understand enough about mipmapping to know when the various levels are automatically being changed to but I'll have a look around and see what I can find. Also, your approach leads me to another solution I over-looked, simply rendering out the dynamic quad-tree to a single canvas material that I update as the user zooms in and out. That way I only need one material (the canvas) tile. That might also help things re: loading as I don't want to pre-load every texture from every level of detail.

Comment: Vertex or pixel shader? In the vertex shader it always uses the highest level of detail for texture2D as it can't infer the mipmap required based on pixel width. However, texture2DLod(sampler2D sampler, vec2 coord, float lod) will tell it which one specifically to use. lod == 0 is largest mipmap, lod == 1 is half size etc.

Comment: Also make sure you set needsUpdate = true on your texture when you update it, else it won't reload to the gfx card

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'm going to mark this as answered as the mipmap approach would definitely solve the underlying quad-tree problem. Because I need to dynamically load / change those textures after the first run my approach will be slightly different (that single canvas texture that is updated with more tile segments later on).